# Swift Unable to call section/row from NSIndexPath object

Tags: ios, swift

I am unable to find/call section or row from NSIndexPath object

> XCode shows an error - Value of type 'NSIndexPath' has no member
>   'section'

```
func myFunc(menuIndex: NSIndexPath) -> (NSString, NSString) {
 .........     
        let section = menuIndex.section

 .........       
}
```

Comment: Did you import UIKit ? Since `section` property is not in `NSIndexPath` that is "general", but `UIKit`, through `UITableView` simplifies it with `section` and `row`, adding these properties to `NSIndexPath`.

Comment: Yes, I had missed to import. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the Problem by importing UIKit

```
import UIKit
```